# yiic webapp problem

Tags: yii

i'm still new to yii framework.
so, i want to try running yiic so that i could see the structure of the files created.

but, i could not run it in console. Does anyone have a solution? thanks.

I'm using wamp on win xp.

i go to the directory of the yiic framework

its in D:\wamp\www\framework\

and run yiic and any other variations per Larry Ullman's blog. but still got: "..." is not a recognizable internal/ external command...

How should i be able to run yiic? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just read this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/cookbook/3/

:)

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to follow yii official documentation.
You can find Installing Yii process step by step here

> documentation> tutorial > The Yii Blog Tutorial > Testdriving with
>   Yii # Installing Yii

here is the link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.testdrive#installing-yii

---

If you getting this kind of error when you try to use **yiic webapp ..\app-name**

**'"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Open the **yiic.bat** file under yii framework folder ( **C:\wamp\www\framework** ) and change the bellow line

```
if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=php.exe
```

to

```
if "%PHP_COMMAND%" == "" set PHP_COMMAND=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe
```

**php5.4.16** this might be change accroding to you php version, please check in C:\wamp\bin\php folder before change

Cheers